# Understanding ELF Binary Size for nostdlib C Program

Tags: c, gcc, ld, elf

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, `gcc` 9.3.0, `ld` 2.34.
I have a simple hello world program that does not use `glibc` or any other library and just uses write syscall. Despite this, my binary size is roughly 8Kb. I'm unsure as to why it is that large and not say 1Kb.

C Program:

```
int
x64_syscall_write(int fd, char const *data, unsigned long int data_size)
{
  int result = 0;
  __asm__ __volatile__("syscall"
              : "=a" (result)
              : "a" (1), "D" (fd),
                "S" (data), "d" (data_size)
              : "r11", "rcx", "memory");
  return result;
}

__asm__(".global entry_point\n"
  "entry_point:\n"
  "xor rbp, rbp\n"
  "pop rdi\n"
  "mov rsi, rsp\n"
  "and rsp, 0xfffffffffffffff0\n"
  "call main\n"
  "mov rdi, rax\n"
  "mov rax, 60\n"
  "syscall\n"
  "ret");

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  x64_syscall_write(1, "hello\n", 6); 
  return 0;
}
```

Built with:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -static -nostdlib -no-pie -masm=intel \
-fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables \
-Wl,--gc-sections -fdata-sections -Os \
hello.c -c -o hello.o

# NOTE: I know more could be done here to shave 
# off a few more bytes, but I feel this is the bulk of it.

ld -e entry_point hello.o -o hello
```

`hello.o` is 1.7Kb.
`hello` is 8.4Kb.

Comment: Why not use the `gcc` command to build directly to executable? The `ld` command could link to libraries or startup object files you don't want. And note that some of the GCC flags and options you provide only pertain to *linking* which you don't do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Removing explicit `ld` invocation with `gcc -Wl,-eentry_point ...` actually increases the binary size from 8.4Kb to 8.5Kb which is another question I have in itself. What flags did I use that pertain only to linking?

Comment: The `l` in `-Wl` is for **l**inker, and is used to pass flags to the linker. `-static` is also for static linking (but might affect compilation as well, I don't know).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I use `gcc -e entry_point ...` and/or remove `-static` I get the same result, i.e. increase in binary size. Are you referring to another way of building directly with `gcc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
readelf -Wl hello

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x40101c
There are 6 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x0001b0 0x0001b0 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000 0x000045 0x000045 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000402000 0x0000000000402000 0x000007 0x000007 R   0x1000
  NOTE           0x000190 0x0000000000400190 0x0000000000400190 0x000020 0x000020 R   0x8
  GNU_PROPERTY   0x000190 0x0000000000400190 0x0000000000400190 0x000020 0x000020 R   0x8
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .note.gnu.property
   01     .text
   02     .rodata
   03     .note.gnu.property
   04     .note.gnu.property
   05
```

Here you can see that the linker created 3 `LOAD` segments: one for the `ELF` header and other metadata, one for `.text` and one for `.rodata`.

Linking with `-z noseparate-code` results in much smaller binary (smaller than `hello.o`):

```
 ls -l hello*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 1384 Apr 26 22:24 hello
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  603 Apr 26 22:22 hello.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1680 Apr 26 22:22 hello.o

readelf -Wl hello

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x40015c
There are 4 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x00018c 0x00018c R E 0x1000
  NOTE           0x000120 0x0000000000400120 0x0000000000400120 0x000020 0x000020 R   0x8
  GNU_PROPERTY   0x000120 0x0000000000400120 0x0000000000400120 0x000020 0x000020 R   0x8
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .note.gnu.property .text .rodata
   01     .note.gnu.property
   02     .note.gnu.property
   03
```

You can shrink this further by removing `.note.GNU-stack` and `.note.gnu.property` sections:

```
objcopy -R .note.* hello.o hello1.o
ld -e entry_point hello1.o -o hello1 -z noseparate-code

ls -l hello1*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 1072 Apr 26 22:38 hello1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1440 Apr 26 22:37 hello1.o

readelf -Wl hello1

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x400094
There is 1 program header, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000c4 0x0000c4 R E 0x1000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text .rodata
```

Comment: Running `strip --remove-section .comment --remove-section .note.* hello` on the ELF binary results in smaller binary than doing `objcopy --remove-section .comment --remove-section .note.* hello.o` which results in smaller object file. I assumed the `objcopy` invocation would've made the object file smaller and the ELF binary the same size as with the `strip` invocation.